# Keyboard command for gnome-control-center ubuntu 13.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, command-line

As much as I tried to figure this out I simply cannot get this to work out the way that I want it to.

Now the usual commands in the terminal command line would be `gnome-control-center`
now normally this command doesn't like to work for me unless I add `sudo` in front of it.
such as: `sudo gnome-control-center`; which prompts me for the usual password, and after which it works like magic.

But what I would really like to know is what the title has it as. What is the keyboard shortcut command to launch the gnome-control-center. Or as the window its self has it: "system settings."

I hope this question isn't terribly convoluted. Especially in spite of all the research I did to come up with nothing any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can add custom shortcut for `gnome-control-center` by opening Keyboard-->shortcuts-->custom shortcuts--> +,
- A new dialog box will be opened.Type settings in the name field and type `gnome-control-center` in the command filed.
- By default it was disabled,right-click on the disabled shows a new accelerator.Now press the key combinations in the keyboard.
- Now pressed key combinations will be assigned.
- Logout and login back to take effect.

Comment: Ahh ok so I did end up having the correct command entered in. I just didn't know I had to log out then back in. thanks for the expedient help with this matter. Also was I wrong while putting the command in the "<>' when referencing the command as a command its self?